# How to check "switch" statements with json data in swift

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, switch-statement

I need to check multiple if conditions in for loop so, i am not able to check like that so how to use `switch` statements with this below code

**code:** here how to turn below code into `switch` statements. please guide me

```
let indexData = searchResult?.result?.search_result?[indexPath.row]


if let servDetls = indexData?.service_details{

for oneSerdet in servDetls{
    
    if self.keyword == oneSerdet.sub_category?.title{
        cell.serviceNameLbl.text = "\(oneSerdet.sub_category?.title?.capitalized ?? "ABC")"
  
    print("keyword: \(self.keyword ?? "") \n here the sub category tite: \(oneSerdet.sub_category?.title ?? "") \n user name: \(indexData?.first_name?.capitalized ?? "")")

    }
    else if self.keyword == oneSerdet.category?.title{
        cell.serviceNameLbl.text = "\(oneSerdet.category?.title?.capitalized ?? "")"
    }
    else{
        cell.serviceNameLbl.text = ""
    }
}
}
```

o/p:  here from the username `Vikas, New` also need to show `cell.serviceNameLbl.text` but not showing why

```
 keyword: ecommerce web site 
 here the sub category tite: ecommerce web site 
 user name: Dips
 keyword: ecommerce web site 
 here the sub category tite: ecommerce web site 
 user name: James
 keyword: ecommerce web site 
 here the sub category tite: ecommerce web site 
 user name: Vikas
 keyword: ecommerce web site 
 here the sub category tite: ecommerce web site 
 user name: Test
 keyword: ecommerce web site 
 here the sub category tite: ecommerce web site 
 user name: New
```

Comment: It doesn't matter. Your issue is about the for loop, you'll get only the test value of it. Could you debug, with at least printing the values and which one you enter? You might understand your issue.

Comment: @Larme, i have edited my post with debug.. print and o/p.. plz check and guid me

Comment: Could you print `servDetls`? You put the print inside a `if`, put them either inside each `if`, or inside the for loop level? Also, since I guess this method is called mutliple times, could your add a print before the for loop, to show when it starts for a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Switch Statement like this

```
switch self.keyword {
case oneSerdet.sub_category?.title:
    break
case oneSerdet.category?.title:
    break
default:
    break
}
```